# Linking Intel Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio and ANSYS Autodyn

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, subroutine, intel-fortran, ansys

I am trying to write a user subroutine in ANSYS Autodyn version 19.3. The requirements to do this are Visual Studio 2017 and Intel Fortran version 17.0.4. I can't access this older version of Intel Fortran, but I downloaded the new Intel oneAPI which has a Fortran compiler.

I haven't changed any environment variables or paths, I simply installed both visual studio and intel fortran, and during the installation they integrated together.

When I build my solution in Visual Studio, I get the build log attached. It says that it was built successfully but i get 219 LNK4099 errors.

**Buildlog1**
[image: Buildlog1]
**Buildlog2**
[image: Buildlog2]
**Buildlog3**
[image: Buildlog3]
**Buildlog4**
[image: Buildlog4]

```
1>ad_usrsub - 0 error(s), 219 warning(s)
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I was wondering if this is causing the outputted executable to not run correctly?

When I run the executable in ANSYS Autodyn nothing happens which makes me think that these warnings are having an effect.

If someone could help me out I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The warnings have no effect on execution. They appear because your link option /PDB told the linker to look for debug information files that were not there. Your screenshots truncate the lines, but I'd guess that your compile commands specified to place the PDB (Program Database) files somewhere else. The default is to include that information in the object file, but the linker couldn't find it there either.

The only thing this hurts is the ability to debug the application.

If you had shown the complete compile and link commands, I might be able to offer more advice. If your compile command has /Zi, remove it, and also remove the /PDB option from linking. If you can't do that, adjust the linker /PDB option to point to the folder where the compiler placed the .pdb files (same as the .obj files, I think.)