# Implementing user subroutines with ANSYS Autodyn - Visual Studio & Intel Fortran

Tags: visual-studio, subroutine, intel-fortran, ansys

I am trying to implement some of the user subroutine examples in the Autodyn User's Subroutines Guide for Ansys 2019 R3.

In the manual it says ANSYS requires Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 and Intel Fortran 17.0.4 for Windows 10, 64 bit.

I have looked online and can't find the intel fortran 17.0.4 compiler available anywhere. There is a new software package called intel oneAPI which as far as I'm aware has taken over from all previous versions. I downloaded both visual studio and intel oneAPI, and they integrated together during the installation.

I tested a practice 'Hello World' script which worked which leads me to believe that everything is working correctly. The problem is when I try to incorporate the subroutine sin Autodyn, nothing happens.

I have created a pdf to show the steps I take to edit and implement the subroutines:

[User subroutine steps pdf](https://smallpdf.com/shared#st=38d1e0db-fd0d-4d4a-ab27-1b56755eb6fe&fn=Using+subroutines+in+ANSYS+Autodyn.pdf&ct=1620661257220&tl=share-document&rf=link)

The problem is that I don' t know if I'm missing a step or if something is going wrong when I compile and build the executable.

If someone could help me out on this I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks,

C

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Code in steps in some pdf is completely unacceptable. Please show all important information including your code **in the question itself**. See [mcve].

Comment: Please do not link to files in personal storage accounts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linking Intel Fortran with Microsoft Visual Studio and ANSYS Autodyn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442351/linking-intel-fortran-with-microsoft-visual-studio-and-ansys-autodyn)